# How to see the logs of docker container running on different ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

- I am running single docker container on two different ports using below command

  `docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER_SECOND}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER_SECOND} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}`

I can see the container is running fine

[image: docker ps result]

My question is How can I see the logs of this docker container.

Every time I do `sudo docker logs database-service -f` I can see the log of container running on **9003** port only.

How can I view the logs of container running on **9113**

Comment: Hi, in my opinion, docker logs doesn't care about ports, It logs all processes running inside your container, or all application logging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The service which I am running as a docker container is node service. It's always showing **9003** port. There is no hard code given to run the service. Whatever parameter I pass using docker run It uses the same one. But I am not able to view the logs for service running on **9113**

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all the logs that was displayed on stdout or stderr in the container.

It has nothing to do with the processes which are exposed on different ports.

If 2 instance is running inside the container and both are showing there logs on system console then you will be getting both logs on the docker logs command for the container.

You can try `multitail` utility to tail more than one log files in docker exec command.

For that you have to install it in that container.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind external volumes to container service logs and see the logs

> docker run -v 'path_to_you_host_logs':'container_service_log_path'
>
> docker run -v 'home/user/app/apache_access.log':
>   '/var/log/apache_access.log'